# How to expose port 8888 on AWS EC2 instance with HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, aws-security-group

I want to expose port 8888 on my AWS EC2 free-tier micro instance. Right now, my security group for the instance has this in bound protocol:

```
Custom TCP Rule      TCP      8888      0.0.0.0/0       Jupyter Notebook
```

Once I set this up, if I go to the https://INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP:8888/ I see a warning screen with

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 
INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). 
Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I click on advanced and then I can finally access the port. But my question is, how can I over come this so I don't ever see this screen (how do I get my SSL approved?). And I've also seen some folks expose a port (ex. 8888) and access it via http://INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP:8888/ (note the http instead of https). How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your setup. SSL can be used in any port, so port 8888 isn't the problem. The problem is that your SSL Certificate is self-signed (not created by a Certificate Authority).

Companies like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) offer free SSL Certificates. It's worth having a look.